# Cordova/PhoneGap: childBrowser UI images low res/chunky (iOS)

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova, childbrowser

I just installed the childBrowser plugin on Cordova(PhoneGap) for iOS and it works fine, however the images used for the navigation of the plugin are appearing either to large or low res (on both iPhone 3gs, 4, and iPad 2).

Was wondering if anyone knew of a way to correct this?

Thanks!

[image: Big, low res icons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randy McMillan has updated the plugin to address this issue: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/commit/b2adead8c70fb0f5ed174b96d5c93a9650a38b6c